# Fragment onBackPressedCustom link to onBackPressed

Tags: android, interface, listener

I have a fragment which controlled all interactions (to speak)

I wonder as I link myonbackpressed, to do the same as the other function onBackPressedCustom

It is complex to understand.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //super.onBackPressed();
    // nothing here
    // HOW I CAN LINK WITH onBackPressedCustom ?
}

public static void onBackPressedCustom(View .., Fragment  .., ...,..,...,.....){
// ALL FUNCTIONS
// All VIEWS/OBJECTS/ETC/LISTENERS/COLLBACKS

}

MainActivity.onBackPressedCustom(etc.)
```

Comment: This seems like a bad way of doing things.
Can you explain why do you even have this STATIC method?

Fragments and activity should not communicate this way. Search for FragmentInteractionListener interface that your MainActivity will implement and your fragment will have inside onAttach method.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all you should not make static function in your activity to call them directly from fragments.
2. Secondly you do not need to make your own onBackPressed because when ever you are on fragment and you press back button the automatically onBackPressed of activity will be called and you can check on which fragment you were so that you can take decisions.

   @Override

   public void onBackPressed() {
       //which Fragment is currently shown
       //take Action

   }
3. If you need to call activity functions you should call them from current activity's reference like this

   ((MainActivity)getActivity()).yourFunction();